# Is there any way to modify vue-good-table pagination style?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs2, vue-data-tables, vue-good-table

`vue-good-table` allows pagination like following:

[image]

But I need pagination like below image:

[image]

Is there any way to have that pagination style using `vue-good-table`?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem no. These are the available types.

https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/configuration/pagination-options.html#mode

Or you can edit the source code.

https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/blob/master/src/components/VgtPagination.vue